# Android Share data between two Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new developer of Android.How we can share the data between two fragment.
Any idea for this problem.i have make the orderFragment and itemfragment user select the item on item screen and press submit the screen redirct to orders screen user have multiple order.if we redirect the screen the data not send to the orders screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Send data between two fragment try below code

```
YourSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
 public void onClick(View v){
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putString = ("KEY",value)  //Here if you want to send Integer value then write putInt
   YourItemFragment.setArguments(bundle);
 }
}
```

In ItemFragment try below code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order, container, false);
    String YourItem = getArguments.getString("KEY");
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its simple to send data between fragments try this

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("YourKeyHere",value);
itemFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

And then in order `Fragment` receive as

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          String item = getArguments().getString("YourKeyHere");
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    }
```